# Timeout on ProtectPay Hosted Payment Page during payment processing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, transactions, payment-gateway, hosted

I am using ProtectPay hosted payment page for payment processing in my MVC site.

I am facing timeout issue.

Following are steps to reproduce the issue

1. Generate a hosted transaction identifier on my website,
2. construct a new URL
3. Redirect user to external website (hosted payment page).
4. User enters Credit Card information and click Submit
5. Processing starts and after few seconds it says timed out and user does not return to my site.

My question is how I can fix this timeout issue on external page, which is not in my control?

Regards,